# Need to cut off some unnecessary information from a JSON file and preserve the JSON structure

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, bash, jq

I have a JSON file

```
[
    {
        "api_key": "123123112313121321",
        "collaborators_count": 1,
        "created_at": "",
        "custom_event_fields_used": 0,
        "discarded_app_versions": [],
        "discarded_errors": [],
        "errors_url": "https://api.bugsnag.com/projects/1231231231312/errors",
        "events_url": "https://api.bugsnag.com/projects/1231231231213/events",
        "global_grouping": [],
        "html_url": "https://app.bugsnag.com/lol/kek/",
        "id": "34234243224224",
        "ignore_old_browsers": true,
        "ignored_browser_versions": {},
        "is_full_view": true,
        "language": "javascript",
        "location_grouping": [],
        "name": "asdasdaasd",
        "open_error_count": 3,
        "release_stages": [
            "production"
        ],
        "resolve_on_deploy": false,
        "slug": "wqeqweqwwqweq",
        "type": "js",
        "updated_at": "2020-04-06T15:22:10.480Z",
        "url": "https://api.bugsnag.com/projects/12312312213123",
        "url_whitelist": null
    }
]
```

What I need is to remove all lines apart from "id:" and "name:" and preserve the JSON structure. Can anybody advise a Python or bash script to handle this?

Comment: after loading json that will be like `dictionary` so just delete other key you dont need
`dict.pop('key', None)` or  `del dict["key"]`

Answer (score 3):

With `jq`:

```
$ jq 'map({id: .id, name: .name})' input.json 
[
  {
    "id": "34234243224224",
    "name": "asdasdaasd"
  }
]
```

Comment: Ah that's a handy command line tool. I have to admit I've never used it before. What query language does it use? It looks similar to JMESPath, but not quite.

Comment: @RoadRunner `jq` uses its own DSL to manipulate JSON. See https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/

Comment: @RoadRunner, you might also like `jtc` (google up `jtc` and `json` - also very powerful JSON processor I created some time back), using jtc the solution would look like: `<input.json jtc -w'<id>l:' -w'<name>l:' -pp`

Comment: Even simpler: jq 'map({id, name})' input.json

Answer (score 2):

Using python, you could first deserialize the JSON file(JSON array of objects) with [`json.load`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.load), then filter out the keys you want with a list comprehension:

```
from json import load

keys = ["name", "id"]

with open("test.json") as json_file:
    data = load(json_file)

    filtered_json = [{k: obj.get(k) for k in keys} for obj in data]

    print(filtered_json)
```

**Output:**

```
[{'name': 'asdasdaasd', 'id': '34234243224224'}]
```

If we want to serialize this python list to another output file, we can use [`json.dump`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dump):

```
from json import load
from json import dump

keys = ["name", "id"]

with open("test.json") as json_file, open("output.json", mode="w") as json_output:
    data = load(json_file)

    filtered_json = [{k: obj.get(k) for k in keys} for obj in data]

    dump(filtered_json, json_output, indent=4, sort_keys=True)
```

**output.json**

```
[
    {
        "id": "34234243224224",
        "name": "asdasdaasd"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
import json

with open('<input filename>', 'r') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

new_data = []
for item in data:
    new_item = {key: value for key, value in item.items() if key == "id" or key =="name"}
    new_data.append(new_item)

with open('<output filename>', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(new_data, f)
```

Answer (score -1):

Covert your JSON into Pandas Dataframe

```
{  

import pandas as pd 
df=pd.read_json('your json variable')
res=df.drop(['url_whitelis','api_key'],axis=1) 
                                          
pd.to_json(res) }
```

Comment: There is no need to use pandas just to remove json keys